# Javascript How to copy from 1 textbox value to many textbox value

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

can somebody give me recomendation how to copy textbox value to another many texbox.
So far i tried :
Document.getelementbyid but not work when textbox with same ID.

Or anyone know how to copy controller post data?

Comment: Id's are supposed to be unique

Comment: The `id` attribute specifies a unique id for an HTML element (the value must be unique within the HTML document). 
Source: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_id.asp but you can use eg. 
[Document​.get​Elements​ByClass​Name()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp)

Answer (score 4):

Use document.querySelectorAll

```js
function myFunction(val) {
  var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input')
  inputs.forEach(function(input) {
    input.value = val
  });
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="txt" value="Hello" onkeyup="myFunction(this.value)">
<input type="text" >
<input type="text" >
<input type="text" >
<input type="text" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Improving on **dbramwell** answer you can use copy button to do so

```js
var copyValues = function(){
  var whatToCopy = document.getElementById("copyMe").value;
  var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input')
  inputs.forEach(function(input) {
    input.value = whatToCopy
  });
}
```

```html
Copy this
<input id="copyMe"/>
<br>
Into
<input class="copyTo" />
<input class="copyTo" />
<input class="copyTo" />
<button onclick="copyValues()">Copy</button>
```